# jq - find parent element based on search result on child element

Tags: json, jq

For the following json file I need to get 'name' element based on search results for that specific entry

eg: json.txt

```
{
  "regions": {
    "var1": {
      "name": "City 1",
      "domains": {
        "var3": {
          "Owner": "Joe"
        }
      }
    },
    "var2": {
      "name": "City 2",
      "domains": {
        "var4": {
          "Owner": "Brown"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried

```
$ jq --arg arg1 'var4' '.regions | if (to_entries[].value.domains[$arg1]) then to_entries[].value.name else empty end' json.txt
```

but that returns

```
"City 1"
"City 2"
```

I want the result to only fetch

```
"City 2"
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pull `to_entries[]` outside the `if ... then ... else ... end` clause:

```
.regions | to_entries[] | if .value.domains[$arg1] then .value.name else empty end
```

This can be shortened to:

```
.regions | to_entries[] | .value | select(.domains[$arg1]) | .name
```